# Unable to select multiple rows on infragistics ultrawingrid with a check box column

Tags: c#, checkbox, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am having below code that successfully adds a check box column to the ultrawingrid, my problem is that when I make a selection by checking a check box on the Select column the count of selected rows of ultrawingrid is not updated and it still shows the count as zero, and also I want to know how to enable multi checkbox selection i.e multiple rows selected...

Below is the code...

```
private void grdPayVis_InitializeLayout(object sender,InitializeLayoutEventArgs e) 
 var gridBand = grdPayVis.DisplayLayout.Bands[0]; 
    if(!gridBand.Columns.Exists("Select"))
    gridBand.Columns.Add("Select", "Select");
gridBand.Columns["Select"].Header.VisiblePosition = 0; 
gridBand.Columns["Select"].Hidden = false; 
gridBand.Columns["Select"].Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.CheckBox; 
gridBand.Columns["Select"].AutoSizeMode = ColumnAutoSizeMode.AllRowsInBand; 
gridBand.Columns["Select"].CellClickAction = CellClickAction.Edit;
```

}

Comment: Checking or Unchecking a cell doesn't mean that the row is added or removed from the SelectedRows collection. If you want to keep a list of the checked cells you should work with the BeforeCellUpdate or AfterCellUpdate or loop on your rows and look at the value of the checkbox cell (This is one of the reasons that adding your boolean column to the DataSource of the grid is better)

Comment: how can I make multiple rows selected on the grid, It doesn't function like a checkbox and acts like a radio button, checking a second box unchecks the first check box already checked...@Steve

Comment: @Steve Can you please throw some light on how to make multi selection and how to add a new column to the datasource, because the stored procedure that is used is being used in various pages of the application and cannot really change it

Comment: You don't change the stored procedure. You get the result back from the stored procedure (I suppose a DataTable) then add a new (bit/boolean) DataColumn to it, set its default to false and set the DataTable as DataSource of the grid. Now, for the grid knowledge, it should automatically update that field. Selecting the rows with your check set to true could simply achieved using the DataTable Select method. How do you set the DataSource of the grid? Could you add that code?

Comment: @Steve this is code below to set the datasource

Comment: ds = new DataSet("PayCharge");
ds= obj.GetData();
grdVisPay.SetDataBinding(ds, "PayCharge");

Comment: @Steve:Can you please share an idea related to this...like how exactly I can add a new column to the data table and loop through it when checkboxes are selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you actually is trying to achieve. When you set *CellClickAction* in your *Select* column to *Edit*, and you click on any cell in this column the grid will select the cell and not the row. Grid has [Selected](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2015.2/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v15.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid~Selected.html) property which exposes three collections - rows, columns and cells. In your case you are changing the selected cells and do not change the selected rows collection. If you need to select rows you need to set *CellClickAction* in your *Select* column to *RowSelect*. If you need in the same time to shange the checkbox state of the *Select* column you may handle *AfterSelectChange* event of the grid like this:

```
private void grdPayVis_AfterSelectChange(object sender, AfterSelectChangeEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Type == typeof(UltraGridRow))
    {
        foreach (UltraGridRow row in this.grdPayVis.Selected.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells["Select"].Value = true; // Or some value appropriate to your scenario
        }

        this.grdPayVis.UpdateData();
    }
```

By default, the grid allows you to select many cells, rows or columns. However, when there is a cell in edit mode you cannot select any other cells. So again, as you have set *CellClickAction* to *Edit* when you click any cell in *Select* column it enters edit mode and no more cells could be selected before you exit edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new column to your datatable AFTER reading it from the database

```
ds = new DataSet("PayCharge"); 
ds= obj.GetData(); 
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Select", typeof(boolean));
dc.DefaultValue = false;
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(dc);
grdVisPay.SetDataBinding(ds, "PayCharge");  
.....
```

Now the first table in your dataset has an unbound column named `Select` and when you set that as your datasource you will be able to manipulate as you have already done. But this time whenever you touch the checkbox the value True/False will be set in the underlying datatable. When you need to discover what are the checked rows you work with the datasource, not with the grid. For example

```
void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DataSet ds = grdVisPay.DataSource as DataSet;
     DataRows[] selectedRows = ds.Tables[0].Select("Select = True");
     foreach(DataRow row in selectedRows)
     {
         ... do whatever you need with the selected row...

     }
}
```

Comment: @SteveThank you so much for the reply, but this still does not allow multi row selection, I added a new data column to the dataset but still I am not able to check multiple checkboxes..

Comment: So if you click on the checkbox nothing happens? Are you able to edit the other cells?

Comment: When I check a checkbox on the grid and click on a textbox control on that winform, the checkbox selection is not able to persist, it again unchecks itself and also I am not able to edit other cells on the grid, how can this behavior of grid be handled...

Comment: Something happens in your grid events handlers?

Comment: I have three event handlers for this grid, Initializelayout, Initializerow, CellChangeevent. the cell change event is to handle the selection of row by check box selection:

Comment: Try to comment out that event handler. It should not be necessary with the column based on a datasource

Comment: What version of the Infragistics controls are you using?

Comment: it is version 11.2..is it related with the version

Comment: I am sorry but I am unable to help more than that. If you wish to prepare a zipped file with your code and upload it to a sharing drive like GDrive or OneDrive and then paste the link here I would try to take a look at your whole code (No promise though)

Comment: I fixed it...grids inititalize row event was causing this behavior, Thank you so much for all your replies...:)